# multiple dimension correlation in c#

Tags: c#, math, correlation

ive got two N-dimensional series of points, each of length M.. the objective is to correlate them and calculate the correlation coefficient.. using formulae for variance, covariance and standard deviation, it is possible to calculate the correlation coefficient..

what i dont understand is how to adapt the algorithm to account for all N dimensions instead of just one.. consider the following..

```
series A = [0, 0] [1, 1] [2, 2] [3, 3]  
series B = [0,  0] [1, -1] [2, -2] [3, -3]
```

if we use only the first dimension for correlation, we'll get +1.00.. if we use the second, we'll get -1.00.. but we can see that if we were to consider both dimensions for correlation, the answer won't be as simple as +1.00 or -1.00..

so i wanna know how to formulate this sort of multiple-dimension correlation, preferably in c#..

feel free to ask for further clarifications or edit to improve the post further.. =)

EDIT: the series im using are stock time series.. i retrieve the latest M samples of CLOSE prices as series A and start correlating it with all historic data as a sliding window (data[1] to data[M+1], data[2] to data[M+2], data[1000] to data[M+1000], and so on).. the offset where the correlation is highest is the point in time where the price behaviour was almost identical to now.. by analyzing if the price moved up or down after that time instance, we can make a prediction which way the price might make a move at this time instant.. but im not using just CLOSE prices (1-dimension).. i want to identify regions where a number of metrics were similar, for instance CLOSE, VOLUME, etc.. so the time series doesnt have just one value for every index but a whole array of values..

if i use just CLOSE in correlation, i cant guarantee if the VOLUME sequence of these series will be similar too.. likewise if i use VOLUME in correlation, i cant guarantee if the CLOSE sequence of these series will be similar too.. so i need a formula for normalized correlation which is based on some sort of distance metric.. something like a^2 + b^2.. if the CLOSE values are similar, a^2 will be small.. if the VOLUME values are similar, b^2 will be small.. now if a^2 + b^2 is small, it means both CLOSE and VOLUME are similar..

previously what i was doing was as follows:
1. use CLOSE prices to calculate correlation.
2. use VOLUME to calculate correlation.
3. multiply these values together.. this will ensure that high correlation values will imply that both CLOSE and VOLUME have strong individual correlations..

EDIT:

```
stdDevX = Sqrt (Summation ((x - Mean(x)) * (x - Mean(x)) / N)
stdDevY = Sqrt (Summation ((y - Mean(y)) * (y - Mean(y)) / N)  
corrXY = Summation ((x - Mean(x) * (y - Mean(y)) / (stdDevX * stdDevY)) / (N - 1)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

the above formulae assume that both series x and y are one-dimensional.. my main concern is how to adapt these formulae for multi-dimensional vectors.. i wish to use it to find regions where all price metrics are similar in history.. but it can be used by anyone who wishes to correlate any sort of vertors.. x,y,z coordinates of an object, etc..

Comment: Is the point to add +1 when they are equal and subtract -1 when they aren't equal?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please add the [homework] tag.

Comment: @matthew.. no it isnt.. its part of a self-imposed personal project that ive been doing since the past six months or so.. it involves identifying where in history did a similar series occur as present.. and using that information to try to predict the next couple of data points.. i can provide more info if needed.. but that would make the question limited in scope so wanted to keep it general to benefit more people.. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the question, but I think you are being asked to treat each series separately. So considering **just** Series A as a sequence of samples from a pair of variables X and Y, the two variables are completely tied (if you drew a scatter plot, all the values would be on a straight line from bottom-left to top-right) so the correlation is +1.

In contrast, considering **just** Series B as another sequence of samples from X and Y, this time a scatter plot would again be a straight line from top-left to bottom right. Increasing X decreases Y. The correlation is -1.

It gets more interesting if each series contains samples from three variables (for example, snapshots of the prices of three stocks over time). Here is a simple example:

```
            X  Y  Z   X  Y   Z   X  Y   Z   X  Y   Z
series C = [0, 0, 0] [1, 1, -1] [2, 2, -2] [3, 3, -3]
```

Here, you need to consider the correlation between *each pair* of variables. In this simple case, the correlation between *X* and *Y* is +1, between *X* and *Z* is -1 and between *Y* and *Z* is -1.

### Edit: Combining correlations

Suppose you have samples from three variables – *close*, *high* and *low* – for two time periods and want to know how good a match the two periods are. You could calculate the correlations between the two time periods for each variable in the traditional way. Suppose this yields *close-correlation* = 0.6, *high-correlation* = 0.3, and *low-correlation* = 0.4.

You need some method of combining the individual correlations into a goodness of fit score in such a way that individual correlations far from zero (i.e. highly correlated, either positively or negatively) have a bigger contribution to the score than those close to zero. Simple approaches include taking the product (0.6 * 0.3 * 0.4 = 0.072) or the root-mean-square (sqrt((0.6^2 + 0.3^2 + 0.4^2) / 3) = 0.4509) – you'll have to experiment to find the method that gives you the most reliable results.

Comment: youre pretty spot on matthew on this one.. this **IS** what im trying.. but i have to consider the joint effect of all the individual variables together and not separately.. for instance if i were to use just the CLOSE prices in correlation, i could find a historic time subsequence where the CLOSE prices followed in almost exactly the same way.. but that doesnt guarantee that other important metrics also followed the same way then too.. for instance the HIGHs and LOWs and other market indicators, etc.. so i need a way to incorporate that into the correlation formulae too..

Comment: So you're looking at two time periods and want to find out if the CLOSE prices are correlated **and** the HIGH prices are correlated **and** the LOW prices are correlated between the two (i.e. if a historical period is a good match for the latest data, the next data points in the historical series *might* also be a good match for what the stock is going to do). Presumably you're looking for the best historical match you can find. So you can still work out the correlations for each variable separately, but you need some formula to combine the correlations into a "goodness of fit"?

Comment: YES!!! =) i need to be able to combine correlations into one single value.. please see the latest edit of the initial question.. ive included formulae for correlation but theyre for one dimension only.. i wanna know how to incorporate multiple dimensions into it..

Comment: hey thanks for the edit.. =).. i was thinking along the same lines myself but yes.. i think youre right in the multiplication of correlations.. i tried it myself a while ago but still wasnt getting good results.. did more research and realized where the fault lay.. its right in the formula for correlation.. ive described it in my follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876101/a-reliable-measure-of-series-similarity-correlation-just-doesnt-cut-it-for-me)..

Answer (score 0):

```
int GetCorrelationScore(Array[,] seriesA, Array[,] seriesB)
{
   int correlationScore = 0;

   for (var i = 0, i < seriesA.Length; i++)
   {
      if (areEqual(seriesA[i][0], seriasB[i][0], 0.5m) && areEqual(seriesA[i][1], seriasB[i][1], 0.5m))
         correlationScore++;
      else
         correlationScore--;
   }
}

bool areEqual(decimal value1, decimal value2, decimal allowedVariance)
{
   var lowValue1 = value1 - allowedVariance;
   var highValue1 = value1 + allowedVariance;

   return (lowValue1 < value2 && highValue1 > value2)
}
```

Comment: i think more information **IS** required.. im trying to use stock value time series to predict its future values.. the idea is that similar price movements result in similar behaviours in price.. so im using correlation.. you will **NEVER** find an exact match in history.. so if we simply add +1 for every identical point and -1 for every differing point, youd get a -M value for all historic time series.. i can provide more information if you want.. but i dont believe its as simple as you put it.. =)

Comment: Added some more detail on how you can add a allowed variance and then step up the correlation score if it's within the allowed range

Comment: thanks mharlin.. but i think you misinterpreted the question slightly.. =).. pearson correlation is defined as follows:

stdDevX = Sqrt (Summation ((x - Mean(x)) * (x - Mean(x)) / N)  
stdDevY = Sqrt (Summation ((y - Mean(y)) * (y - Mean(y)) / N)  
corrXY = Summation ((x - Mean(x) * (y - Mean(y)) / (stdDevX * stdDevY)) / (N - 1)  

[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient)

here x and y are the two series that i want to correlate with each other.. but it assumes that the data series (continued)..

Comment: (continued)..
are one-dimensional.. how is it possible to update this formulae so that it takes into account multidimensional data..

hope ive been more clear this time.. =)